# No value in my dropdown my database is oracle

Tags: php, oracle

What is the problem of my code? There is no value in my dropdown can you please help me? thanks!

```
    <select name="product_cat">
        <option>Select a Category</option>
        <?php 
        $c = oci_pconnect(ORA_CON_UN, ORA_CON_PW, ORA_CON_DB);

        $s = oci_parse($c, 'SELECT * FROM Categories ORDER BY cat_id');
        $r = oci_execute($s);

        while ($row= oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)!=FALSE){

        $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
        $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];

        echo "<option value='".$row_cats['cat_id']."'>".$row_cats['cat_title']."</option>";

        }

        ?>
    </select>
    </td>
```

Comment: Your variable is called `$row` not `$row_cats` - use the built-in error reporting to tell you about these things: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: thank you i already change it but nothing change my dropdown still nothing

Answer (score 0):

change the line

```
while ($row= oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)!=FALSE){
```

to

```
while ($row_cats= oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)!=FALSE){
```

As in the subsequent code you are using row_cats variable

Comment: i already change it but there's still no value in my dropdown